# Common generic class to handle server response in flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm calling requesting server for data and getting following response.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kurti"
    },
    {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Top"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Data fetched"
}
```

Modal class to convert json data coming from server.

```
class Product {

  String categoryName;
  int productId;

  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    categoryName = json["id"];
    productId = json["name"];    
  } 
}
```

So from the server the format will be fix for every call like below...

```
{
   "success": <Int>,
   "message": <String>,
   "data": <An array of Model class>
}
```

For that I've created below class...

```
class ServerResponse<T> {

 String message;
 int success;
 List<T> data;

 ServerResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    message = json["message"];
    success = json["success"];
    data = json["product_data"];
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling api...

```
class ServerManager {

  final baseUrl = isProduction ? liveServer : stagingServer;

  var headers = {"consumer-key": "sdfgdqwrtw34563t545"};

  dynamic callWSToGetData({Map<String, String> params}) async {

    var client = http.Client();
    var url = baseUrl + allProducts;
    print("URL = $url");
    print("params: $params");
    print("header: $headers");
    var response = await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: params);

    var json = converter.jsonDecode(response.body);
    return json;
  }
}
```

Calling api to get data as following.

```
Map<String, String> params = {"categories_id": "1", "language_id": "1", "type": "Newest", "customers_id": "0", "page_number": "0"};
var response = ServerManager().callWSToGetData(params: params);
var res = ServerResponse<Product>.fromJson(response);
print(res.data);
```

So when I ran this code I'm getting following error.

**type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Map'**

The question is...

1. How can I create a single generic class that can be used to handle server responses?

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

This is probably due to missing await call. Your `callWSToGetData` has async in declaration so it's type will be Future.

To use generics you need to pass the type. So your code will look like this:

```
var response = await ServerManager().callWSToGetData(); //how can I use generic here
var res = ServerResponse<Product>.fromJson(response);
print(res.data);
```

Comment: I'm using await here.  `var response = await client.post(url, headers: headers);`

Comment: I've done changes suggested by you and getting this `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: If you put async in your function declaration the return type is always a Future and you need to await it, the same as in JavaScript.

Can you see which line do you get this error?

Comment: I've added debug point and when line comes to this line error appears in console.`var response = await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: params);`

Comment: Please update your question, since this is different code. Seems like `params` is another `Future` and you need to `await` it.

Comment: you still haven't included the `await` required by @pr0gramist